# Azure Machine Learning pipeline: How to retry upon failure?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

So I've got an Azure Machine Learning pipeline here that consists of a number of `PythonScriptStep` tasks - pretty basic really.

Some of these script steps fail intermittently due to network issues or somesuch - really nothing unexpected. The solution here is always to simply trigger a rerun of the failed experiment in the browser interface of Azure Machine Learning studio.

Despite my best efforts I haven't been able to figure out how to set a retry parameter either on the script step objects, the pipeline object, or any other AZ ML-related object.
This is a common pattern in pipelines of any sort: Task fails once - retry a couple of times before deciding it actually fails.

Does anyone have pointers for me please?

Edit: One helpful user suggested an external solution to this which requires an Azure Logic App that listens to ML pipeline events and re-triggers failed pipelines via an HTTP request. While this solution may work for some it just takes you down another rabbit hole of setting up, debugging, and maintaining another external component. I'm looking for a simple "retry upon task failure" option that (IMO) must be baked into the Azure ML pipeline framework and is hopefully just poorly documented.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that if a script fails, you want to rerun the entire pipeline. In that case, it is pretty simple with Logic Apps. What you need is the following:

1. You need to make a PipelineEndpoint for your pipeline so it can be triggered by something outside Azure ML.
2. You need to set up a Logic App to listen for failed runs. See the following: https://medium.com/geekculture/notifications-on-azure-machine-learning-pipelines-with-logic-apps-5d5df11d3126. Instead of printing a message to Microsoft Teams as in that example, you instead invoke your pipeline through its endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm looking for something that is baked into the Azure Machine Learning framework. It is a task orchestration framework after all so there must be a retry mechanism available within?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think what I described above is the canonical way. You’d be surprised how easy it is to process Azure Machine Learning events by Logic Apps - the GUI makes it easy to create a webhook that re-triggers your pipeline.

Comment: So I've given your suggestion a try and while I agree setting up a logic app is easy enough getting this to run correctly seems to open another can of worms: For instance, matching runStatus on string Failed doesn't seem trivial - doesn't work for me anyways. So now I'd end up debugging an extra level on top of my ML pipelines.

Comment: So I've dug around further and managed to parse runStatus correctly. I already published for each of my pipelines a pipeline endpoint that provides me with a URL I can POST against to re-trigger a pipeline run. So far so good - but now I need to handle authentication with this URL from within my logic app, i.e. fetch a bearer token, pack that into the header for my POST etc. This seems like a lot of overhead for something that should be built into the Azure Machine Learning pipelines framework? I just fail to see how all this overhead would be the canonical way here.

Comment: I think it would be eaiser if you assigned a managed identity for the Logic App, and then give that managed identity access to the endpoints. Then you don't have to mess with token authentication. 

But I agree, when you add in authentication it gets a bit more cumbersome than it should be.

Comment: Thanks again. So I set up a managed identity for my logic app with the contributor role for the machine learning service and also added an authentication parameter (under "other parameters") in the logic app http action. Now I'm getting an "UnsupportedMediaType" error response when POSTing to my pipeline endpoint to re-trigger it ...

Comment: I've tried a couple of Content-Type parameters now and always get a 415 UnsupportedMediaType error in response. I assigned you the bounty for trying to help me out but I fail to accept that this approach is anywhere near best practice solution for a simple and obvious problem as mine. This is a task management framework we're talking about here so it must provide a built-in "retry upon failure" option without needing to open a can of worms with a plethora of other external services.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I'm sorry I couldn't get it to work. I'll try to find time to cook up a demo with authentication. You may find the following relevant: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-publish-and-run-using-rest-endpoint.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

(this would ideally be a comment but it exceeded the word limit)

@user787267's answer above help me set up the re-try pipeline. So I thought I'd add a few more details that might help someone else set this up.

**How to set up the HTTP action**

```
Method: POST 
URI: The pipeline endpoint that you configured 
Headers: `Key`: Content-Type -- `Value`: application/json 
Body: 
{ 
  "ExperimentName": "my_experiment_name", 
  "ParameterAssignments": { 
        "param1": "value1", 
        "param2": "value2" }, 
  "RunSource": "SDK" 
} 
Authentication Type: Managed Identity
Managed Identity: System-assigned managed identity
```

You can set up the managed identity by going to the logic app's page and then clicking on the Identity tab as shown below. After that just follow the steps. You'll need to give the managed identity permissions over the space in which your ML instance lives.

[image: tab for identity]